# Are the .htaccess rewrite rules causing my query string to be empty?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Here's my problem:

- I'm sending a query string called **'sort'** through **$_GET** to a PHP script
- The script recognizes the query and I can use it
- 5 seconds later I call the same PHP function, but the query is empty
- Also I mention that the query is visible at all time on the URL **&sort=new** so I can see it there I just can't use it except the first time
- Also I've tried parsing the URL and garbing the query directly but it's also empty
- I need it to work as it should and be able to use the string as many times as I call the PHP script

Because I'm using some rewrite rules my URL looks like this (no .php which I'm guessing might be the problem)

```
example.com/group/groupName?&sort=new
```

Below are all the .htaccess rewrite rules used and I think they might causing the issue

```
RewriteRule ^group/?$                                       index.php?a=group                           [NC]
RewriteRule ^group/([^/]+)/?$                               index.php?a=group&name=$1                   [QSA]
RewriteRule ^group/deleted/([^/]+)/?$                       index.php?a=group&deleted=$1                [NC]
RewriteRule ^group/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$                       index.php?a=group&name=$1&r=$2              [NC]
RewriteRule ^group/([^/]+)/search/([^/]+)/?$                index.php?a=group&name=$1&search=$2         [NC]
RewriteRule ^group/([^/]+)/friends/([^/]+)/?$               index.php?a=group&name=$1&friends=$2        [NC]
```

All these ReWrite rules are used on the site but I can't figure out if it's them that are causing the problem or it's something on the PHP code.

Edit:
I'm using in htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

This is how I"m trying to get it with PHP:

```
$parts = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
$sortBy =  $query['sort'];
```

Comment: _"my URL looks like this"_ - how do you mean that? Your URL looks the way you type it into the address bar or as a link looks like. So the question for me is how you are _"sending a query string"_

Comment: What I meant is - that's how my URL should be looking without any rewrite rules. I'm submitting a form with a 'sort' text input.

Comment: But how do you know how your URL looks?

Comment: sidenote: It would be much easier to handle if you'd send _everything_ after `^group/` to index.php as a parameter and do the rest of routing there.

Comment: I've removed the first part because I guess it confuses everything. The URL above is what I see on the search bar.

Comment: Then it's a link in your (generated) html. What you see in your address bar is what you type/send _before_ it hits `RewriteRule`. htaccess rewrites _from_ address bar _to_ php-server.

Comment: I'm almost certain the issue is with the rules because I changed the flag of the second one from NC to QSA after reading for a while and I managed to make the query work but it only works 1 time. Second time the script is called it's empty. I didn't build the code, I'm just trying to make some edits and understand it btw.

Comment: maybe you use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] somewhere? It's hard to tell if we don't see the code of the link and how it's generated...

Comment: Yes, I'm using that. I've edited the thread.

Comment: and then later you use `$parts['path']`? Check what that is. And please show the complete generation of the link. This way I can only guess what you could have done, that maybe could have gone wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184111/discussion-between-csgotalks-com-and-jeff).